# Testing using Jest, how to expect result to be an array of Components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

The code of my test is as follows:

```
it('makes sure the list items are populated', () => {
    var view = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Sidebar />)
    var result = view.populateLi();
    expect(result).toBe(Array);
});
```

The result is supposed to be an array of Components called `ListItem`.

```
Expected: [Function Array]
Received: [<ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />, <ListItem … />]
```

How do I write a test to match the `Received` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use [scryRenderedComponentsWithType](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#scryrenderedcomponentswithtype):

```
     var result = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(view, ListItem);
```

As this will return an `Array` of `ListItem`s, all you need to do is to check that the length of the array is what you expect:

```
  expect(result).length.to.equal(12); // or however many you expect
```

If you want to check your `populateLi` function works you should probably right a separate test:

```
var result = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(view, ListItem);     
var populateResult = view.populateLi();

expect(result).to.deep.equal(populateResult)
```

Comment: throws an error : `ReferenceError: ListItem is not defined`

Comment: You need to `import` or `require` it in the same way you're bringing in `SideBar`

Comment: The test still fails `Expected: [Function Array]
    Received: [[ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem], [ListItem]`

Comment: Also I wanted to check if `populateLi()` works properly. It is supposed to return an array of `ListItem` components.

Comment: What exactly does `scryRenderedComponentsWithType` do?

Comment: It finds all instances of the component you specify in the tree you pass in. See the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#scryrenderedcomponentswithtype